# Подсчитать число столбцов матрицы, в которых есть неотрицательные элементы

Tags: c++

Здравия! Нужно найти число столбцов в матрице, в которых есть неотрицательные элементы(хотя бы одно число>0). Удалось написать программу, которая считает число строчек в которых есть неотрицательные элементы. Очень прошу помочь.

`

```
for (int i{}; i<real_rows; i++)
{
for (int j{}; j < real_columns; j++)
 {
if (arr[i][j]>=0)
     {
     k++;
     break;
      }
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < real_columns; j++)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < real_rows; i++)
  {
    if (arr[i][j] >= 0)
    {
      k++;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```